# Pause flow of code until JTextField has gotten an input?

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

I currently have a JTextField whose input is set to perform an action, and then erase itself so another command can be entered. However, under certain circumstances, I have a separate loop run. It's made to check for different actions, and one of these is to prompt the user for a certain input. This uses text files along with buffered reader to determine what to do. Currently, the code is as follows:

```
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.split("@@")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("move"))
            {
                CommandTriggers.move(line);
            }

            if(line.split("@@")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("display"))
            {
                CommandTriggers.display(line);
            }

            if(line.split("@@")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("choice"))
            {
                CommandTriggers.choice(line);
            }

            if(line.split("@@")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("branch"))
            {
                CommandTriggers.branch(line);
            }       
        }
```

All of these are fine, except for the "choice" option. I am able to make this class read the action listener instead of the default class, however I am unsure how to make this "pause" until the user has given input. If I do not do so, it will simply skip past and run the rest. A sample layout of the text file is as follows:

```
display@@Some sort of yes or no prompt.
choice@@yes@@no
branch@@branchYes@@branchNo
```

In effect, it would display the prompt, and then wait for input. Depending on what was input, one of the branches would be chosen. I'm just not sure how or if I can do this.

I really apologize for the horrid formatting of everything. I hope I was able to explain the issue I'm having. If there's anything I can clear up (and I'm sure there is), I'll try my best to do so.

Comment: Disable the current JTextField and use a Modal dialog to prompt the user or save the current state and wait till the field triggers another update

Comment: I'd rather avoid using a popup prompt, but I'm not sure what you mean by or how to carry out the second option.

Comment: Build up a "current" state (the information you have), when needed, stop processing. Once you have more information, using the current "state" continue processing. You "might" be able to use a thread which "locks" on a monitor lock until more input is gained

Comment: Just remember, you can't block the edt ;)

Comment: Haha it looks like I'll have to do some studying on that. I'm almost completely self-taught, and I've not had to do anything of this sort in my basic experience. Thanks for the advice, I'll look into that soon.